# Java JTwig For Loop Using A Range Not Container

Tags: java, for-loop, jtwig

I want to be able to do the equivalent of the following loop using a JTwig template:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) { ... }
```

I have tried the following but neither seem to work:

```
{% set k = 10 %}
{% for i in 1..k %}
    <option value={{k}} >{{k}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Or

```
{% set k = 10 %}
{% for i in range(1,k) %}
    <option value={{k}} >{{k}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

I can loop containers but can't seem to find a way of getting this kind of thing to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add square brackets, like so:

```
{% for i in [1..10] %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

I discovered this rather by accident. It seems to be missing from the documentation.